# Clustering location data ignore outliers

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, geometry, google-visualization, cluster-analysis

I am doing a **clustering of GPS locations**.

I got around 4000 data points and I used the **Kmeans** clustering algorithm.

Here is the the results I got:
[image]

The markers are the real data position, while the green circle regions(centroid) are the kmeans outcome.

You can see the top right hand clustering, which is **affected by some outliers**.

Is there any method to get rid of the influence of outliers in order to find out the accurate clustering centroid? Thank you

============================================================

The GEOdata I got has the following format:

```
[
{"lat": 22.28552,
 "lng": 114.15769
},
...
]
```

The kmeans algo I am using is follow [here](http://www.mymessedupmind.co.uk/javascript-k-mean-algorithm/). But I changed the distance into `distance = Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2))`

Comment: That result doesn't look right. Can you create a fiddle or post some code? How do you initialise the centroids?

Comment: @MattWay I updated my question. The centroids are calculated by the mean of the data corresponding to the cluster, like `(x1+x2+...+xn)/number_of_point_in_cluster1,(y1+y2+...+yn)/number_of_point_in_cluster1 `

Comment: Yes, but how do you initialise them? Where do they start?

Comment: I choosed the number of cluster = 5. And the initialization of cluster centroid : data_array[data_array.length/number_cluster]

Comment: That Kmeans code you referenced seems buggy to me if i am not mistaken. For example in line 087 it looks to me as if it should be `newCentroid=total/Groups[j].length;` changing newGroup for index j. Also the doubled if-else-statement in the lines 51 and 58 with same body do not make me trust that code. Maybe better write your own - it's pretty easy.

Comment: Also note that using an euclidean distance for lattitudes and longitudes will probably not give you what you might expect as e.g. 1°longitude = 0km at the north or south pole and 1°longitude ~~ 40000/360 km at the equator... it's a sphere after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K-means is a poor choice for such data.

1. it is sensitive to outliers
2. it does not work with Haversine distance (don't use Euclidean on geo coordinates!)

Popular choices for such data include DBSCAN and OPTICS.